# Better practice to find the max/min element in a loop

Tags: ruby

Is this the most elegant way to avoid declaring additional variables outside the       `following_triggers` loop?

```
      closest_trigger_utc_time = (2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1)
  following_triggers.each do |test|
    closest_trigger_utc_time = test.utc_time if test.utc_time < closest_trigger_utc_time
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

[Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) has many useful methods that solve problems like this. In this case you want `map` and `min` or `min_by`:

```
closest_trigger_utc_time = following_triggers.map{|test| test.utc_time}.min
```

`2**(0.size * 8 -2) -1` is a bad way to write infinity. If you must have an infinity value, use `Float::INFINITY` instead, but it's better to avoid this. `min` returns `nil` for empty input, so it's convenient to use that as the default value, or replace it with something else by `closest_trigger_utc_time || some_meaningful_default`.

Comment: `min_by` is better because it replaces `map` (so no extra array).

Comment: @steenslag: yes, although that requires repeating `.utc_time`, since the OP wants the time, not the element with that time.